# Adding before element style?

Tags: css

How to add background color to cell when i have this html?

```
<td><div class="color">RED</div></td>
```

I want to add background color to **td** but i dont want to add class or ID to that **td**, is it 
possible to that like .color:before

Comment: we have `:before` but looks like you misunderstand its usage.

Comment: If your question is about laying a color over the parent's element , then the pseudo-element is a way to do so : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/exGJF . If this is your question and answer , then reformulate the question to ropen it. i'll add then this as an answer.